# Can the Host provide the link key to the Controller with Bluetooth?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I was wondering whether the Host can provide the Link Key to the Controller with BR/EDR Bluetooth, and Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE). (v4.2)

The [BT Core Spec v4.2](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/adopted-specifications) says:

> #### 7.1.10 Link Key Request Reply Command
>
> ```
> Command                       OCF       Command Parameters       Return Parameters
> HCI_Link_Key_Request_Reply    0x000B    BD_ADDR, Link_Key        Status, BD_ADDR
> ```
>
> The `Link_Key_Request_Reply` command is used to reply to a Link Key
>   Request event from the Controller, and specifies the Link Key stored
>   on the Host to be used as the link key for the connection with the
>   other BR/EDR Controller specified by `BD_ADDR`. The Link Key Request
>   event will be generated when the BR/EDR Controller needs a Link Key
>   for a connection.
>
> <sup>**Source:**
>
>   Bluetooth Core Specification v4.2
>
>   > Vol 2: Core System Package [BR/EDR Controller volume]
>
>   >> Part E: HOST CONTROLLER INTERFACE FUNCTIONAL SPECIFICATION
>
>   >>> 7.1.10 Link Key Request Reply Command</sup>

It seems to be only valid for BR/EDR (Classic Bluetooth) and not for Low Energy. However, the spec is not very well written and it might be that this part was not updated to imply a compatibility with BLE. Moreover, I can't simply use this command to make the Host send a Link Key to the controller; the controller must send a `HCI_Link_Key_Request` before.

Hence my question:

- Can I make the Host provide the Link Key to the Controller for BR/EDR and BLE?

Answer (score 2):

The HCI command you mentioned is used for BR/EDR. This is used only for authentication after the pairing was successfully done before. so once two devices are paired , on connection depends on the security Mode ( assuming security Mode 4 level 4), does a mutual authentication , This involves the controller asking the Host for the linkkey stored in the host earlier. The HCI command you mentioned is used to supply this linkkey stored in host back to controller. if the host doesn't have a linkkey then the host issues a HCI_Link_Key_Request_Negative_Reply this results in a failure on the initiator with Key or PIN missing error code.

in case of LE HCI_LE_Long_Term_Key_Request_Reply is used for the same purpose.

on your question about whether it is able to provide the linkkey without beeing asked for it , for BR/EDR you can use HCI_Write_Stored_Link_Key, but this is generally not very useful as on turning off bluetooth, the controller forgets the linkkey. on LE there doesn't seem to have an equivalent HCI interface.

Answer (score 0):

Link key cannot be provided by host to controller, on authentication procedure, link key will be generated by controller and send to host(link key is generated using lot of parameters, please check BT Spec)